# why list.append cannot work in DFS algorithm

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, depth-first-search

not sure about the problem, so might misleading in the title. this question from LC 77. below is my code, but it returns

> TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()

however, if I change `path.append(lis[i])` to `path + [[lis[i]]`, the code works well and passes the test. what's the difference between these two? Thank you!

```
def combine( n: int, k: int) -> List[List[int]]:      
        res = []
        lis = [i for i in range(1,n+1)]
        visited = set()
        def dfs(lis, path):
            if len(path) == k:    
                res.append(path)
                return
            for i in range(len(lis)):
                dfs(lis[i+1:], path.append(lis[i]))
        dfs(lis, [])
        return res
```

Answer (score 1):

`path.append()` returns `None` and modifies `path` in-place. You probably meant to call `path.append(lis[i])` before recursively calling `dfs(lis[i+1:], path)`